# Resizing Flash in IE8 is buggy

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, actionscript

**Problem**

When resizing a Flash object in IE, it's resize handler incorrectly thinks that only the stage width has been updated.

**Steps for reproducing the bug**

1. You roll over and click a Flash
   button
2. The button makes an
   ExternalInterface call to JS. JS
   resizes Flash among other things.
3. In
   all non-IE browsers, Flash is
   notified of the dimension change and
   executes its resize handler flawlessly. 
   In IE8,
   the resize handler is called but is
   only its stage width has been updated. It still believes its height is the same.
4. To finally get IE8's Flash to acknowledge its true height, roll your mouse out of the SWF.

**Actionscript**

```
package {
 import flash.external.*;
 public class Player {
  public function Player(container:Stage) {
   this.container.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, this.onResize);
  }
  public function expand():void {
   ExternalInterface.call('expand');
  }
  public function onResize():void {
   // float chrome buttons to the right
   // float chrome to the bottom
  }
 }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// Using Prototype framework
function expand() {
 $('flash').setStyle({
   width: '500px',
   height: '400px'
 });
 // do other stuff in JS too
}
```

The listener gets triggered fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer. There's no problem with the Javascript - I see the Flash getting resized. But the Actionscript listener doesn't get fired until I my mouse moves out of the SWF. What do I need to know about IE's rendering engine to fix this?

**Before**

[image: before]

**After** - IE's Flash is notified of the width change, but still thinks it's height is the same.

[image]

**Move mouse out of SWF** - you must roll your mouse out of the SWF for Flash to acknowledge its true height in IE8

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting Flash's height a 2nd time. Even though it's set to the same height, it tricks IE to redraw the page.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why that is, But I would suggest (or strongly recommend) that you add a callback on the flash side, and trigger it from javascript to force the call.

look into `ExternalInterface.addCallback`

I could go on about how to get that part (js <-> Flash communicaiton) working, but someone's already done that.

http://www.viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication/

Comment: I have tried to use ExternalInterface to explicitly call Flash's resize handler right after Javascript does the resizing, yet it is still broken in IE. It seems as though IE's DOM manipulation is not synchronous. That is, if I make the ExternalInterface call right after the DOM changes, the ExternalInterface call is not gauranteed to be executed *after* the DOM change.

Comment: It doesn't even help if I delay the ExternalInterface call for 5 seconds to gaurantee that AS resizes after JS resizes. For some reason, the mouse must leave the SWF in IE for AS to be notified of its new dimensions.

Comment: what about getting IE only to move the content off screen `left: - 9000px` for 10ms and then move it back. 
Also, have you tried playing with the focus on the javascript end. Just stabbing in the dark here

Comment: I ran into similar problems when dealing with the VLC web plugin. I've tried similar techniques to fix IE: 1) moving Flash off the screen, then back on. 2) Blur the focus. 3) Scroll the page down 1px then up 1px. They've worked for VLC, but not for Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out?

http://manos.malihu.gr/resize-flash-dynamically-with-javascript-and-actionscript

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this. I used CSS to place the swf in a block, and use `overflow:hidden;` to hide anything outside of my parameters. Worked easy in ie8.